# nmea_serial_driver: GPS device is giving same lat/lon reading

Tags: robot-localization, gps, ros-galactic

### background info

ros2 - galactic, Cyclone

##### Note: The laptop is disconnect from wifi during testing, just to avoid any problem caused by poor wifi connection outdoor.

### question

I am having a very strange issue with my GPS after launching with nmea_navsat node.

The problem is that from time to time, when I was feeding the */fix* topic from the GPS node to robot_localization while launching **Nav2**, **rviz2**, and some other hardware node, the */fix* publish the **same** lat/lon when the robot moves. However, when I turn off **Nav2** and relaunch the rest of the system, the GPS and odometry(output from robot_localization) is **updating correctly again!**
Moreover, this **does not happen every time** when I launch the node.

For example, in today's testing.
The GPS device publishes the correct reading to /fix when I launch the system, including **Nav2**, and the robot is navigating to the goal. (See [rosbag](https://bju-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/sdu568_students_bju_edu/EkmPu3hdpARHtbNMEN60MksBVoYO7HgCpVuQZzdT6sge0Q?e=ocIgJm))  However, when I turn it off and relaunch the **same system** with the **same configuration**, the /fix is giving off the **same lat/lon reading(base on the replay from rosbag)**, even after the robot moves for couple meter(more than 5 meters, which is outside of the covariance of the GPS), see [rosbag](https://bju-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/sdu568_students_bju_edu/EkmPu3hdpARHtbNMEN60MksBVoYO7HgCpVuQZzdT6sge0Q?e=jMSdkt).

Thus, I am wondering if that is a hardware configuration issue with my nmea_navsat node? Or does that has anything to do with Nav2 configuration?

Below is my configuration for my nmea_navsat (I modified base on the [example](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver/blob/ros2/config/nmea_serial_driver.yaml) )

```yaml
nmea_navsat_driver:
  ros__parameters:
    port: "/dev/ttyUSB0"
    baud: 57600
    frame_id: "gps_link" # note: gps_velocity depend on this 
    time_ref_source: "gps_link"   
    useRMC: False
```

By the way, I have publish a static_transform from my GPS ("gps_link") to base_link

````py
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration

#TODO: comeback to correct later
# use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true') 
def generate_launch_description():
    imu_to_base_link = Node(
            package="tf2_ros", executable="static_transform_publisher",
            arguments=['0','0','0','0','0','0','base_link', 'imu_link'],
            # parameters=[{"use_sim_time":use_sim_time}]
        )
    gps_to_base_link =Node(
            package="tf2_ros", executable="static_transform_publisher",
            #arguments=['0','0','1','0', '0','0','base_link', 'gps_link'],
            arguments=['0','0','1','1.5707963', '0','3.1415926','base_link', 'gps_link'],  # transform NED to ENU frame
            # parameters=[{"use_sim_time":use_sim_time}]
    )
    camera_to_baselink = Node(
            package="tf2_ros", executable="static_transform_publisher",
            arguments=['0','0','0','0','0','0','base_link', 'camera_link'],
            # parameters=[{"use_sim_time":use_sim_time}]
    )
    return LaunchDescription(
        
        [
            imu_to_base_link, gps_to_base_link,camera_to_baselink
        ]
    )

```
````

Comment: Do you have a way of checking if the GPS is actually receiving a signal? I wonder if this is its way of telling you it doesn't know where it is...

Comment: Hmm. Let me try to use the cli tool to double check tomorrow.  Thanks for the advice!  I will let you know how it go.

Comment: @sdu568 did you ever figure this out? If so, can you update the question?